# Are there (portable) AC units that also ventillate?

Tags: air-conditioning, ventilation

If I understand correctly, (portable) AC units like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Whynter-14-000-BTU-Portable-Air-Conditioner-with-Dehumidifier-Heat-and-Remote-ARC-14SH/202555706) one take inside air, cool it and push it back inside, and similarly take outside air, warm it and push it back outside.

**Afaik, This means that airconditioning and ventillation are somewhat at odds with each other**: The AC unit requires airsealing the room (to an extent) to prevent heat getting back in, but this means we don't get ventillation. In particular, CO2 builds up to higher levels than it would if we had proper ventillation.

Afaik, this problem is partially solved by combining AC with Heat Recovery Ventilation, but these are separate systems that have to be installed in the house, i.e. aren't portable and not in the same system as the AC unit.

**Maybe this is too much to ask for, but are there portable AC units that combine air-conditioning with ventillation somehow?**

NOTE: I'm not asking for air-filtration, but for ventillation, i.e. actually replacing indoor air with outdoor air. Filtration-only systems cannot reduce CO2 levels.

Comment: Unless the room is air tight and very well sealed, usually do not need to worry about CO2 levels  Electrical units/devices do not add CO2 to a room.  Humans and burning fossil fuels do.

Comment: The referenced unit is a variation on a "window air conditioner".  Some window air conditioners can be set to draw in outside air, and some can't.  You'd have to dig into the specs of the unit to figure out this one.

Comment: Laser printers add ozone, that's a piece of electronics you'll want to have ventilation for.

Comment: Curious if there is a unit that combines ventilation with heat recovery *and* AC functions in one box btw! Newer homes tend to be better air sealed, especially when specific standards like Passivhaus (DE) are applied.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for an air conditioner (or a heater in the winter) to work efficiently, it needs to work with *mostly* conditioned air. Outside 90 F. Inside set to 74 F. Initial cooling - doesn't matter inside or outside air. But once the inside air is at the set point (74 F), *maintaining* that is **much** easier if you are going from 76 F to 74 F (repeat...) than trying to cool 90 F air down to 74 F just to bring the indoor temperature down by 2 degrees.

There are similar issues with humidity, but just looking at temperature should be enough to understand the problem.

Historically, houses were not very well sealed, so there was always enough air seeping in through cracks around doors, windows, etc. to make sure there was enough oxygen coming in and CO2 going out. Modern houses tend to be far better sealed, and there are solutions to that problem. But with a window/portable air conditioner I suspect the problem is that the unit is way undersized. If it is undersized then it will struggle against even a little bit of super-hot incoming air, leading to sealing the home really well, which then leads to the oxygen/CO2 problem. You don't want too large a unit as that will lead to other problems, but proper sizing can make a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

The unit you linked to has two ducts that go to the window, one to bring in outside air, and the other to exhaust it again.

Most older Portable AC units only have a single pipe going out. Instead of pulling outdoor air into the unit, they cool some of the indoor air and use some of the indoor air over the outside coil and then exhaust it.

This makes it less efficient, but it also accomplishes what you are trying to do because additional air needs to be drawn into the room to replace the exhausted air.

The YouTube channel *Technology Connections* has [a video](https://youtu.be/_-mBeYC2KGc) explaining this.

Comment: Note that single pipe portable AC units have by far the worst coefficient of performance, and therefore the highest electricity consumption for the same amount of cooling power. Considering present day (and expected future) electricity prices, this is important to consider.

Comment: Actually, single-hose have nearly taken over the market.  The 2-hose ones are now black swans.

Comment: It seems to me that single-hosed designs don't accomplish very much ventillation compared to an actual ventillation system, and has the downside of energy inefficiency. I doubt it would be very helpful, but obviously haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

### That house vents the same as the rest of the time.

Most older houses are a lot more "leaky" than you realize. This leakiness has always provided plenty of ventilation.  In fact, historically obtaining makeup air for gas appliances like furnace and water heater (or dryer) has never been a problem, just because houses were that leaky.  That leakiness provides plenty of make-up air for human requirements.  It's not a problem.

For exceptionally tight modern houses, they do make plain ventilators and heat-recovery ventilators. There are even humidity-recovery ventilators which do that and also try to transfer humidity.   This is important, since humidity is a huge factor/cost in air conditioning.

But tight design doesn't forget about air conditioning, because that *invites* open windows and window-unit A/Cs or portables. So I doubt you have a tight house.

However your 2-hose portable, that simply is not its job.  A combo unit doesn't make any sense from a design POV. Realistically, most window inserts are so leaky that it takes care of the problem.

A 1-hose portable might be imagined as a solution, however it's not.  The units have many, many serious problems, especially in tight houses.  The 1-hose unit will try to pull a vacuum on your house. If your house is leaky enough for that to be OK, your house has plenty of ventilation that way.

Comment: "This sounds like some sort of propaganda against 2-hose units, implying 1-hose units change the air better. No, they're just awful units all-around." What kind of nonsense is this? Are you genuinely claiming I am trying to "propagandize" for single hosed units? I am just asking a question about ventillation.

Comment: This is a complete non-answer. Could just have well said "no I don't know of such an AC". The question was not about 1 vs 2 hose designs.

Comment: "Most of the time you're not air conditioning... right? Well, how does your house ventilate then?" Having a window open at all times, or better yet 2 windows.

Comment: @user 1. I didn't mean to suggest you were spreading propaganda, only that you had been influenced by it, but sorry... removed.  2. We don't do shopping questions here. 3. If you leave windows open **while you are running your heater**, then sure, feel free to do the same during A/C season.

Answer (score 0):

There  might be some out there but I haven't seen them. The function of an AC unit is to cool the air. If it's also bringing in hot air to ventilate, it will be inefficient. Same holds true if the unit has a heat cycle. There are dual fan setups that fit in window opening you can use for ventilation by having one fan turning clockwise and the other counterclockwise.

Comment: Well, theoretically you could use heat recovery ventillation so that it wouldn't necessarily be inefficient (but I wouldn't be surprised if there just aren't any available AC units that also have HRV).

Comment: @user56834  If you left both the intake and exhaust inside, you' just be circulating inside air. If you left the intake hooked up right and the exhaust inside, you'd get little ventilation  because the air would have to be vented somewhere.